# Function Guava apply Function on Single object

Tags: java, guava

It seems like very easy but I didn't found an explanation  of how to apply a Function form guava api on single object

for example I have the following function

```
Function<Integer, Integer> powerOfTwo = new Function<Integer, Integer>() {
    @Override
    public Integer apply(Integer input) {
        return (int) Math.pow(input, 2);
    }
};
```

And I want to apply it on

Integer i = 6;

How do I do it

Same on predicate how can I Predicate on single object

Answer (score 3):

## Just call `Function.apply`.

```
final int applied = powerOfTwo.apply(i);
```

A [`Function` is simply an `interface`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Function.html) that defines one method:

```
T apply(F input)
```

Your `powerOfTwo` is simply an [anonymous `class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/anonymousclasses.html) that implements the `Function` `interface`.

The same is true for `Predicate`.

Note, that in Java 8, there is a [whole host of `Function` types](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/package-summary.html) and with lambdas your code becomes:

```
Function<Integer, Integer> powerOfTwo = i -> i * i;
```

Or, using the `int` version (so that you don't autobox to `Integer`):

```
IntFunction powerOfTwo = i -> i * i;
```

You ask *can i chain as well ?*. The answer is in Java 7, no. Because the Guava `Function` `interface` defines only one method there is no way it can provide that functionality. You need to use the [`Functions`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Functions.html) utility class to [`compose`](http://docs.guava-libraries.googlecode.com/git/javadoc/com/google/common/base/Functions.html#compose(com.google.common.base.Function,%20com.google.common.base.Function)) multiple functions:

```
Function<Integer, Integer> composed = Functions.compose(powerOfTwo, powerOfTwo);
```

With Java 8, due to [default method](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/defaultmethods.html) the `Function` interface can actually offer vast amounts of functionality whilst still only having one `abstract` method. Therefore in Java 8 you can do:

```
Function<Integer, Integer> composed = powerOfTwo.compose(powerOfTwo);
```

Or even:

```
Function<Integer, Integer> composed = powerOfTwo.compose(i -> i + 2);
```

Comment: can i chain as well ?

Comment: What exactly do you mean?

Comment: Lets say I want to apply another function on the result.
like 
FluentIterable.from(mylist).filter(new filter1()).filter(new filter2());

Comment: @MosheTsabari you mean **compose**. This is when you create a `Function<A, C>` by combining a `Function<A, B>` and a `Function<B, C>`. In any case, all of the functionality you are mentioning (`Function`, `FluentIterable`) is **wholly** superseded by Java 8; I would suggest you study that instead as learning obsolete technologies is rarely productive.

Comment: I know that but I am working on project with Java 7 not Java 8 off course I would use lambda expression if I could